# python type error: a is undefined

Tags: python, variables, types

Python newbie here. I am writing a program to count how many times a substring is a string, but keep receiving the error message: TypeError: a is undefined. I have looked at /googled similar threads but the code is usually convoluted and hard to follow.

Here is my code:

```
def stringcount(char, word):
for eachChar in word:
    if char==eachChar:
        count=count+1
        return count
    print count

stringcount('a', 'apple')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In case you don't know you can also call the function `count` on string, e.g. 'apple'.count('a')

Comment: Your return statement is going to short circuit your function... also, is your indentation correct here?

Comment: @sr2222 is right - and your indentation is messed up.

Comment: ...and count isn't initialized!

Comment: This is not the code you are using. It cannot produce the error you describe. *However*, this code uses `count` before assigning it a value, so you'll get `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: Betting this is homework, probably not supposed to use `string.count()`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila What package is `char` a predefined function of in Python?  `chr` is, but not `char`.

Comment: You are correct, confused it with `chr`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Agreed, and `stringcount(a, 'apple')` raises a NameError, not a TypeError.

Answer (score 4):

```
def stringcount(c, word):
    count = 0
    for eachChar in word:
        if c==eachChar:
            count=count+1

    return count

>>> stringcount('a', 'apple')
1
>>>
```

But in this case you can simply use:

```
>>> 'apple'.count('a')
1
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is dangerous. You aren't initializing `count`, so if `count` exists as a variable in the namespace you could get a different result every time. For example, if you call the function multiple times, `count` will not reset and the second time the function is called it will return `2`. The following code is much safer and works.

```
def stringcount(char, word):
    count = 0
    for eachChar in word:
        if char==eachChar:
            count += 1
    return count

>>> stringcount('a', 'apple')
1
```

Also note that you can simply do `'apple'.count('a')` to do the same thing.

A nice one-liner does the same thing:

```
def stringcount(char, word):
    return sum(x==char for x in word)
>>> stringcount('p', 'apple')
2
```

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the need to initialize count within the function namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't writing this for a programming exercise, you could do:

```
def stringcount(c, word):
    return word.count(c)

print stringcount("a", "apple")
```

Docs: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.count

Comment: Why define a function at all? The OP can just call `'apple'.count('a')`.

Comment: @mutzmatron: Clearly, but I'm following the functional syntax of the OP.

Comment: I see what you mean, though I agree with @sr2222 in the sense that if this is some kind of assignment the OP probably has to define their own full function, and otherwise no function is required at all. I don't really see a point in the halfway answer?... but then who knows!

Comment: I also forgot about `string.count()`. Anyway, some people may be more comfortable with functional syntax than object oriented syntax. Never mind Zen 12 :)